# cambiar la primera letra a mayusculas php

Tags: php

tengo un código que convierte la primera letra de una oración en mayúsculas ahora bien cuando convierte me cambia los caracteres con acentos a signo interrogante ? por que no lo se.

Ejemplo: en la oración esta escrito:

***lápiz amarillo***

cuando ejecuto el código hace esto:

***L?piz amarillo***

este es el código:

```
$tabla_mayus_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_WEB . "");
    while ($tabla_mayus = tep_db_fetch_array($tabla_mayus_query)) {
        $tabla_mayus2 = ucfirst(strtolower($tabla_mayus['descripcion']));
        tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_WEB . " set descripcion = '" . $tabla_mayus2 . "' where descripcion = '" . $tabla_mayus['descripcion'] . "'");
    }
```

Comment: Si los datos tienen un juego de caracteres _multibyte_, como UTF8, deberías usar funciones que lo soporten, por ejemplo: [mb_convert_case($cadena, MB_CASE_TITLE)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-convert-case.php)

Comment: vale he probado esto pero me convierte la primera letra de cada palabra en mayusculas, solo necesito la primera palabra en mayusculas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitivamente el problema es la codificación que utilizas en tu proyecto. Entiendo que necesitas incluir acentos y ñ, por lo tanto UTF-8 es un camino. Lo que ocurre que deben sincronizarse bien los cambios porque los datos provienen de una base de datos. Entonces las tablas que alojan los caracteres también deben ser UTF8 compatibles.

Para ir de lo mas simple a lo mas complejo...

En el código PHP, podes utilizar el siguiente cambio

```
$tabla_mayus_query = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_WEB . "");
while ($tabla_mayus = tep_db_fetch_array($tabla_mayus_query)) {
     $tabla_mayus2 = ucfirst(mb_strtolower($tabla_mayus['descripcion']));
     tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_WEB . " set descripcion = '" . $tabla_mayus2 . "' where descripcion = '" . $tabla_mayus['descripcion'] . "'");
}
```

Si te fijas, reemplazo strtolower por mb_strtolower, que es una adecuacion que incluye php para lidiar con estos caracteres especiales.
Podes ver mas detalles en [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtolower.php)

Un poco mas complejo es revisar las tablas de base de datos. Esto es necesario porque si las mismas no están alineadas con UTF8, cuando extraigas los datos van a codificar lo ya codificado y se verá mal.
Para ello el instructivo que mas resultado me dió es este
https://www.liviubalan.com/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-on-ubuntu-server
y la prueba rapida es ir al phpmyadmin de tu proyecto y en la consola de mysql ejecutar

```
show variables like 'char%'
```

Debes esperar algo asi o similar, donde puedes observar que la codificacion de las tablas y variables char es utf8

```
Variable_name   Value   
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

Te dije que era complejo, pero neecsari para que cuando cargues datos latinos respete los caracteres especiales.

Ojala esta informacion te sirva.